# Automatically inserting laziness in Haskell

Tags: haskell, semantics, strictness

Haskell pattern matching is often head strict, for example,`f (x:xs) = ...`
requires input list to be evaluated to (*thunk* : *thunk*). But sometimes such evaluation is not needed and function can afford to be non-strict on some arguments, for example `f (x:xs) = 3`.

Ideally, in such situations we could avoid evaluating arguments to get the behaviour of `const 3`, which could be done with irrefutable pattern: `f ~(x:xs) = 3`. This gives us performance benefits and greater error tolerance.

My question is: Does GHC already implement such transformations via some kind of strictness analysis? Appreciate it if you could also point me to some readings on it.

Comment: I don't know for certain but I'm pretty sure it does not try to do that. Irrefutable patterns exist for a reason. that reason being the intended difference in semantics between the two definitions you showed, just as you've described them. AFAIK strictness analysis seeks to *reduce* laziness and perform the unavoidable computations earlier, if it can be proved it won't change the semantics. But these are just hunches and impressions that I have. Perhaps a close reading of [the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/) will provide more definitive answers.

Comment: If we bring this reasoning to its extreme, we should also "optimize" `seq x y` to `y`, which would defeat the purpose of `seq`. A strict pattern, in principle, could be used as a special case of `seq`.

Comment: The ~ changes the semantics of the function, so ghc doesn’t do that.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, GHC will never make something *more lazy* than specified by the programmer, even if it can prove that doesn't change the semantics of the term. I don't think there is any fundamental reason to avoid changing the laziness of a term when we can prove the semantics don't change; I suspect it's more of an empirical observation that we don't know of any situations where that would be a really great idea. (And if a transformation *would* change the semantics, I would consider it a bug for GHC to make that change.)

There is only one possible exception that comes to mind, the so-called "full laziness" transformation, described well [on the wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/FAQ#When_can_I_rely_on_full_laziness.3F). In short, GHC will translate

```
\a b -> let c = {- something that doesn't mention b -} in d
```

to

```
\a -> let c = {- same thing as before -} in \b -> d
```

to avoid recomputing `c` each time the argument is applied to a new `b`. But it seems to me that this transformation is more about memoization than about laziness: the two terms above appear to me to have the same (denotational) semantics wrt laziness/strictness, and are only operationally different.

Comment: It's worth noting that the suggested change in the original question *does* change semantics wrt laziness - it removes some possible bottoms. Sometimes you want very precise control over what bottoms can result from code, and the compiler switching that up on you is awkward.